# Kivy - re-focusing input field not possible?

Tags: python, kivy

i have the following example using kivy -

When i write something in the input field1 and press Reset - everything works fine (input field get deleted, focus on field1).
But when i am changing something in field2 and press the Reset Button it seems that the App gets broken...

Why is that and why is the statement `self.ids.stockTicker.focus = True` not working every time?

py-file:

```
import threading
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window


Builder.load_file("TryApp.kv")

class MyLayout(Widget):
    Window.size = (550, 700)

    def Reset(self):
        self.ids.stockTicker.text = ""
        self.ids.stockTicker.focus = True
        self.ids.index.text = "SP500"

    def pressReset(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.Reset).start()

class MyTry(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyTry().run()
```

kv-file:

```
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: (1, .5)
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Field1"
                font_size: 18
            TextInput:
                id: stockTicker
                focus: True
            Label:
                text: "Field2"
                font_size: 18
            TextInput:
                id: index
                text: "xyz"

        Button:
            id: buttonReset
            text: "Reset"
            #font_size: 20
            on_press: root.pressReset()
            size_hint: (None,None)
            width: 110
            height: 70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to change:

```
        on_press: root.pressReset()
```

to:

```
        on_release: root.pressReset()
```

The reasoning is that when the `pressReset()` method is triggered by the `on_press` event, the focus is changed as you desire, but then the `Button` release event changes focus back to the `Button`. Changing it to the `on_release` event eliminates that problem.